# mongodb частичный поиск через $regex

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения, mongodb, search, mongoose

Знаю, что в монго нету частичного поиска из коробки и нужно искать через `$regex`, но как искать через него сразу по нескольким полям документа?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю, что так:

```
db.collection.find({$or:[{firstName:{$regex:reg}}, {lastName:{$regex:reg}}]});
```